What is the purpose of a bootable partition if GRUB is installed in the first 512 of the disk?
The flow from hardware boot (BIOS/UEFI) that passes off control to bootloader which loads the OS makes sense to me.
Bootable partitions make sense to me.
Bootloader responsibilities make sense to me.
So theoretically BIOS would look for a bootable partition and load the bootloader from that partitions and off to the races.
However,  I read that GRUB stage 1 is installed in the first 512 of the disk along with the partition table.
So what's the point of a bootable partition at that point if grub is in the MBR and will just take over and load stage 1.5 from it's internal configuration no matter what?

IIRC you only need one if you're going to use one GRUB installation to boot multiple OSs (then each OS should be configured to dump kernel images and initramfs files in that common partition). When doing the partitioning myself for a single OS installation I stopped used one during the BIOS days.

Grub does not really care but for any Grub code to run, BIOS has to boot it first. Some BIOS refuse to boot without this flag. Some BIOS refuse to boot with this flag. Annoying.

With old BIOS installs, part of grub is in MBR, part in space between MBR & first partition and in /boot. As well as configuration files & scripts in your install. A /boot partition is often used with server installs or LVM with full drive encryption. But BIOS/MBR has not been the standard since Microsoft required Windows to be installed in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives. Then either an ESP - efi system partition or if BIOS boot a bios_grub partition is required (no space after gpt's protective MBR). UEFI/gpt with an ESP should be the way most systems are installed in. /boot optional


BIOS would look for a bootable partition

If you (and @frostschutz) are talking about a partition that is marked as "active" (or "bootable") in a MBR/DOS partition table, the flag/attribute is neither for BIOS nor grub, but for the boot code of some bootloaders that is written on the MBR, which is loaded by the BIOS, to determine which partition it should look at for boot code that should be further loaded.
The approach is NOT used by grub, but some other bootloader, such as the one used in Windows. (But of course, it's a whole different story for "everyone" when it comes to UEFI booting.)
Because grub-install writes a "core.img" (I don't know if it has like a proper or official name, but IIRC that is/was what it is called in the official documentation), which is somewhat like an extended part of its early boot code (which is written to the MBR), or, the "VBR boot code" that is written to the "active" partition in the case of Windows, to the gap between the MBR and the first partition (or a "BIOS boot partition" if you are installing a BIOS variant of grub to a drive with GUID Partition Table, due to the fact that there is no gap allowed between the Protective MBR and the primary GPT by design). Since the location is "fixed" (or, can be determined by looking for the first partition with the specific type GUID), grub does not need to make use of the active flag.
Some sort of hint that is similar to the active flag (in certain cases it could be a UUID or so, I think, but I don't really know that much about its internals) would be embedded in this "core.img", so that the "basic" part of grub would be able to determine which partition consists of its "root", which is where stuff like grub.cfg and modules that were not included in the "core.img" are installed to. (For your information, if you see the "grub rescue", it means that this "basic" part of grub for some reason is not able to find where its "root" is.)
By default this "root" is the same place as the system's /boot, which can either be directly under the root of a dedicated filesystem / partition that would be mounted on the system's /boot, or it could be simply the /boot directory of the system's /, depending on whether you want to have a "separate /boot partition".

I don't have the concrete pros and cons of having a separate /boot partition for you, but one case I just thought of, a niche one perhaps, is that if your system's / filesystem / partition resides on a drive that grub and/or the BIOS/UEFI does not have the driver / support for, a separate /boot partition would allow grub to still be able to load the Linux kernel (and initramfs). Once the kernel is loaded, the "context" would be switched to OS level, where a driver for the drive would like be available, the system's / filesystem can therefore be mounted. (TL;DR, it's the story of wanting to use an NVMe drive as the system drive in an old machine, and you can have just the /boot partition on a SATA or USB drive)

Thanks for the info!  Interesting stuff.  Another niche one for separate boot folder is an encrypted volume.

Do you know how BIOS identifies a bootable volume? I thought it was a bootable partition but I'm off on that.

@NickKiermaier Not really sure what you are referring to. Either way, BIOS itself does not identify anything, it just load / execute boot code on the MBR (of the drive you chose / on the top of the boot order), whereas UEFI looks for a EFI executable file at a path set in a boot entry or a fallback path. UEFI implementations typically enumerates files at the fallback path that can be found on the first partition with a filesystem it supports on each drive. Some (e.g. AMI Aptio) look at every partitions. Usually they support FAT(12/16/32), some has driver for NTFS as well.

@NickKiermaier If you are talking about like the Windows context, the closest thing I could relate to a "bootable volume" is "a partition with (appropriate) VBR boot code written on it". AFAIK, the VBR boot code is responsible for loading NTLDR
or BOOTMGR (i.e., the core / "later-stage" part of a Windows bootloader / boot manager).

@NickKiermaier Btw, it is possible for grub to open a LUKS volume, so It is not strictly necessary for you to have a separate /boot partition to have encrypted /, but certainly having to mess with only the initrd / initramfs would probably make things easier.

Thanks! So BIOS just looks at MBR and not 'bootable' partitions, that's more in the bootloaders domain.  I think that's been where my knowledge gap has been. That's crazy that UEFI can read file systems nowadays! Good to know! Also, crazy that GRUB is so advanced that it can read LUKS! Thank you so much for the help!
